# PHP Read Variables from a second page (NOT get / post)

Tags: php, dynamic, file-get-contents

I am sure this is answered on this forum but I can't find the answer so here goes:

I have a webpage template.php. It has lot of code but in between there is:

```
      <!-- Hero Content -->
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="home-text">
              <h1 class="hs-line-8 no-transp font-alt mb-50 mb-xs-30"> DISCOVER </h1>
              <h2 class="hs-line-12 font-alt mb-50 mb-xs-30"> <?php echo $saved_data['title']; ?>  </h2> <?php echo "<img src='$saved_data['builderimagepath']'>"; ?> 
              <div class="local-scroll"> <a href="#register" class="btn btn-mod btn-border-w btn-medium btn-round hidden-xs">Register</a> <span class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;</span> <a href="#features" class="btn btn-mod btn-border-w btn-medium btn-round">Learn More</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <!-- End Hero Content -->
```

Key lines are:

```
<?php echo $saved_data['title']; ?>  
<?php echo "<img src='$saved_data['builderimagepath']'>"; ?>
```

Now the second web page read.php wants to read the variable names being used. Hence I want to know how to get "title" and "builderimagepath" in an array in read.php.
( I can rename the variables as a key or as a multi-dimensional array in template.php )

In read.php, this is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$url = 'index.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<?php echo $saved_data' , $content );
$second_step = explode("']; ?>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0]; // Will Add to array to process

?>
```

We are NOT passing variables through GET / POST from template.php to read.php , but read.php wants to get it in an array. What I want to know:

1) Is there a better approach?
2) What is the best way to name variables in template.php , so its easier to access and process in read.php?

I don't think its relevant but $saved_data is an array coming from a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
// Read from file
if (empty($_GET['file'])) {
  // Use default file:
    $filename = 'mydata.txt';
    $saved_raw_data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $saved_data = unserialize($saved_raw_data);
} else {
    $saved_raw_data = file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
    $saved_data = unserialize($saved_raw_data);
}
?>
```

Comment: your scraping your own (raw files) site?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ezw no one knows, it makes little sense, I'm betting on the classic x-y problem, but the OP is AFK so no help for him.

Comment: Currently read.php has bunch of textbox, file uploads etc. Client can fill in information, in extreme non technical way. That generates mydata.txt . Then template.php creates a beautiful website using the data from the mydata.txt. my client has to generate lot of websites which have same structure with different info. What I am trying to do now with next version is make read.php dynamic. It reads all the variables and their values from mydata.txt and setup textbox and image upload correspondingly. Hence, I will not have to modify read.php each time variables change in template.php

Comment: I am just coming back to programming after 10 years. Never did PHP before but I love this Lang. Sorry if I am doing rookie mistakes / don't know basics.

Answer (score -1):

In the file that you want to store the variables, return the values as an array and you can catch them in another file when including into a variable.

template.php

```
return [
        'var1' => 'value',
        'var2' => 'value2
      ];
```

read.php

```
$variable = include('template.php');

print_r($variable);
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? (not my down vote. Just sayin')

Comment: The OP wants to get the variables used in the template in an array. The template contains HTML (where the variables are used).

Comment: _"Now the second web page read.php wants to read the variable names being used. Hence I want to know how to get "title" and "builderimagepath" in an array in read.php."_  - `mydata.txt` is just where the template gets the contents of those variables from. The OP wants to parse the template (html) to see what variables are being used in it.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question. Let me improve on it. Is he trying to build a sort of a template engine?

Comment: That is correct. You said it so elequently ezw. What am I doing wrong? Am I reinventing the wheel? What can I do better?